# What is the function of ποτὲ in «πολλάκις ἐθαύμασα τίσι ποτὲ λόγοις Ἀθηναίους»? (Xenophon, Memorabilia, 1.1.1)

Tags: greek, xenophon

> πολλάκις ἐθαύμασα τίσι ποτὲ λόγοις Ἀθηναίους ἔπεισαν οἱ γραψάμενοι Σωκράτην ὡς ἄξιος εἴη θανάτου τῇ πόλει.

[Source](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0207)

My question concerns the usage of ποτὲ in this clause. I reviewed the LSJ entry for the word, and if I am not mistaken, Xenophon must be using it to intensify his wondering (i.e., ἐθαύμασα). Is this correct?

[LSJ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pote%5C&la=greek#lexicon):

> III. 3. [select] with intensive force, in questions, τίς ποτε; who in the world? “τίνες ποτ᾽ ἐστέ;” A.Eu.408, cf. S.Ph.220, etc.; τί ποτ᾽ ἐστὶ τοῦτο τὸ πάθος what it can possibly be, Pl.Tht. 187d; “οὐκ ἐξερεῖς ποτε;” S.OT335, cf. 754, Aj.1290, etc.; to strengthen ἀεί, ἀεί ποτε from all time, always in the past, “ἀεί ποτε ζῇ ταῦτα” Id.Ant.456, cf. Aj.320, Th.6.82, al., D.C.42.5; “ἀεὶ δή π.” Th.1.13, 8.73.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. "What on earth were their arguments?" is the sense. This suits the context (Xenophon, who's on Socrates' side, finds it hard to imagine how the Athenians could have been persuaded against him), and the temporal sense of ποτε doesn't really fit here.